# Run process (net.exe or sc.exe) with Administrator privileges at the end of an installation in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

In the `[Run]` section of my script I want to run the `net.exe` with the parameter `start MyService`. The `Flags` are:

- `waituntilterminated`
- `runhidden`
- `postinstall`

If the setup is run explicitly as administrator with the *"Run as administrator"* option, the service gets started after the user hits *"Finish"*.

If the setup is just double clicked (`PrivilegesRequired` is set to `admin`) the service doesn't get started.

This also happens with the `sc.exe`

What do I have to do, so that the service gets started at the end, no matter what the user did to run the setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`runascurrentuser` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection):

> If this flag is specified, the spawned process will inherit Setup/Uninstall's user credentials (typically, full administrative privileges).
>
> This is the default behavior when the `postinstall` flag is not used.