# Run batch file as admin, hidden, from inno setup

Tags: batch-file, permissions, inno-setup, admin, prompt

I have an Inno Setup installation which successfully run a batch file when finished. The batch asks for admin rights, gets them and does things.

I've been asked to completely hide the prompt window, so I've added "Flags: runhidden" in Inno Setup and @echo off and >nul 2>nul in the batch. But the batch still flash a prompt window, because of this:

```
if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & goto 
batch & exit /b)

EXIT /b

:batch
---MyCodeHere---
```

I have not written this code by myself and I'm not expert about batch programming, but I'm pretty sure that these lines open a new prompt with admin permissions, and that's the prompt flashing.

Does anyone know if there's a solution to this? Maybe some flag to add to "powershell start", or another completely different way to do this task.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: maybe rather just use vbs to hide it from view, including any flashes. `Set MyScript    = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyScript.Run "D:\SomeDir\scriptname.cmd", 0, False` then launch the vbs script instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the batch file ask for Administrator permissions.

Run the batch file with Administrator permissions straight away:
[Run process (net.exe or sc.exe) with Administrator privileges at the end of an installation in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38377907/850848)

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\my.bat"; Description: "Run my batch file"; \
    Flags: postinstall runascurrentuser runhidden
```

Comment: Still don't know: the fact is this app must be installed on a system where users can use only the shared desktop and we don't know at 100% what permissions are available. Probably, it will be installed by a system administrator anyway, but we are still waiting for the test in that environment.

On my local machine works, but here I am the admin.

Comment: Do you set `PrivilegesRequired` directive? + If the user does not have Admin privileges, your elevation code in the batch file won’t help either.